# Exp from Sizzling Summer Event

Tags: runescape

Is the Exp from the sizzling summer event given to a random skill, or can we chose which skill the exp goes to?

Answer (score 2):

The [Sizzling Summer FAQ](http://services.runescape.com/m=forum/l=0/sl=0/forums.ws?16,17,49,63904591) says:

> How will this free XP be delivered? Will it be the same way the different SoF lamps work?
>
> UPDATED: The XP will be delivered in a way that will allow you to distribute it amongst your skills as you see fit. Please keep a look out for more information in the coming weeks!

So, you can choose how to distribute it.